# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.hot.accept') app crash

Tags: react-native

**This makes the app crash almost instantly during launch:**

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

**This is working fine (for months!):**

```
react-native run-android
```

---

- MacOS
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.56.0
- App was initialized using React Native v0.55.0
- Used: react-native init XyzApp

---

Have any of you ever faced this issue? Please help.

[image: LogCat screenshot]

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+F `hot.accept` and find out why might there be `e` or `hot` undefined